# Basic property and confusion of group law of an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field.
I have a question about elliptic curve $Y^2Z=Z^3-XZ^2\subset \Bbb{P}_K$. I want to know what is the line which go through $[2:\sqrt{6}:1]$(This can be regarded as affine point $(2,\sqrt{6})$ in affine coordinate $Z\neq0$)) and $[0:1:0]$(infinite point).

This should be $x=2$, but I'm confused because $(2,\sqrt{6},1)$ goes through $x=2$,but $[0:1:0]$ never go through $x=2$.
Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: $X=2Z$ looks OK?

Comment: Oh, my god. You are correct, then it is $x=2$ in affine chart.